# Combinations-identical objects

Tags: combinatorics

There are $p$ copies each of $n$ different subjects. Find the number of ways in which a non empty selection can be made from them. Also find the number of ways in which at least one copy of each subject is selected.
In this question I am confused with the difference between non empty selections and at least one selection. Aren't they same? Also answer of 1st part is $(p+1)^n-1$ while the answer of 2nd part is $p^n$. Don't both parts have same answer $p^n$?

Comment: Please format your questions. The most important point is to put formulae etc between $. [Look at my edits above]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part you are asked for the number of ways of selecting any number of objects except zero. For the second part you are asked to select at least one of each type.

So if there was just 1 copy of each of 3 objects, for the first part you could select all three objects or just two of them or just one of them. For the second part you would have to select all 3.

In the first part you have $p+1$ choices for each type of object (ie $0,1,\dots$ or $p$), so $(p+1)^n$ in all, but we must subtract 1 because the case where we select 0 in every case is disallowed.

In the second case you have $p$ choices for each type of object, so $p^n$ choices in all.